# Visual Studio 2012 loses intellisense in MVC 4 Razor views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing a project with plug in ASP.MVC architecture. We use one main web application project and multiple subprojects. My problem is following - Visual Studio loses intellisense in MVC views in a subproject. On one developer machine it works while on another it doesn't. I know we need some NuGet packages to be installed, I know we need Web.config in Views directory. It's all configured and still after moving into another developer machine it stops working.

I've tried:

- IIS reset
- Visual Studio reset
- Running visual studio with elevated privileges
- PC reboot
- Creating new web project
- Deleting suo file
- Deleting csproj.user file
- Installing ASP.NET and Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012
- Reseting VS environment settings

And still when I run project in other developer machine it doesn't support intellisense in my subproject.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .suo file? Also, do you have any vs add-ins they do not?

Comment: I've just tried and it has not helped, but thank you. When it comes to the add-ins I'm not using anything like ReSharper or something like that. Only relatively small things like AutoT4MVC.

Comment: I would consider disabling them and giving it a test

Comment: I'm doubtful, because they don't affect intellisense in the main web project.

Comment: I really think you should (just temporarily) disable ALL your plugins and see if it comes back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution. I've modified Web.config of subproject and added following code to it:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
      <!-- New -->
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

I also changed web subproject properties, on the Web tab I unchecked "Apply server settings to all users (store in project file)".

Comment: Good work, but why didn't you have this if all other users did?

Comment: I guess the lack of those config may be caused by choosing Empty not Basic or another version of MVC project while creating it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Wrong - it's not caused by Empty project template. But in various versions of VS it could work or not as far as I've checked.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. When codebase is large, intellisense can be lost.

Some of developers in our team were struggling with that for a long time. But installed [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It always worked fine for us after that.

I think you have to wait for a patch, or install try to install Resharper, it's free for 30 days.

Comment: Due to company policy it's not a solution for me.